# Which is or Which are?

Tags: relative-pronouns

Could you please check if the following sentence is grammatically correct:

"There are a number of reasons for this trend, which **is** having a significant impact on both family life and on the community as a whole."

I think it should be "which are" instead of "which is" as I think "which" modifies "a number of reasons", which is a plural noun phrase.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you're referring to the trend, then it's singular, **is**.

Had you been referring to the number of reasons, then it would have been plural, **are**.

The trend is having an impact, the number of reasons isn't.

Comment: Dear Tetsujin. Thank you very much for your analysis. It is very helpful. Thank you!